# How can I make a chat app with nativeScript?

Tags: ios, nativescript, chat, nativescript-vue

I need to implement a chat into my app and im not sure on what to use and how. I don't know what is required for creating a chat, do I need to use some special stuff or is it enough with posting the messages to a database and then the other user retrieve that message?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebase MBaaS with NativeScript, to make a chat app.
Or you can also take another approach and use QuickBlox, Parley, Applozic, Connectycube, etc.

Comment: Here is a link to ConnectyCube NS Chat code sample https://developers.connectycube.com/js/native-script

Comment: Okey, can i even use mongo DB with socket.io also?

Comment: Yes, there is socket io plugin for nativescript.

Comment: Note that the services I mentioned, including QuickBlox, Parley, Applozic, and connectycube, almost all of them officially support NativeScript and provide official plugins I guess. There is also full Firebase plugin for nativescript.